# How to get token in Python 0AuthLib OLX Partner API V2

Tags: python, api

I study API OLX https://developer.olx.ua/api/doc. I'm trying to implement authorization and getting a token in Python. Stuck at the moment of receiving the Authorization Code. I am a beginner, I have never worked with this type of authorization.

Here is my piece of code

```
client_id = 'xxxx'
client_secret = 'xxxx'
authorization_base_url = 'https://www.olx.ua/oauth/authorize'
token_url = 'https://www.olx.ua/api/open/oauth/token'
redirect_uri = 'http://www.example.com/'     # Should match Site URL
scope = 'v2 write read'
grant_type='authorization_code'
import hashlib
import requests
from authlib.integrations.requests_client import OAuth2Session
olx = OAuth2Session(client_id, client_secret, scope=scope,redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
authorization_uri, state = olx.create_authorization_url(authorization_base_url)
user_agent_val = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'
payload={'username': 'example@gmail.com','password': hashlib.md5(b"xxxxx")}  
headers = {'User-Agent':user_agent_val}
response = requests.request("GET", authorization_uri, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.url)
```

I expect to receive in a variable response a string of the redirect_url/code&state, but I get string authorization_uri
If I enter line authorization_uri into the browser after authorization, I am redirected to the required redirect_url/code&state
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things here. You first need to construct Authorize url with expected parameters like `redirect_uri`, `grant_type`,`client_id`, `client_secret` and `state`. `state` here would be some random string that is an identifier for your state. Some auth providers expect `PKCE` strings.

For eg. Auth Url can be `https://www.olx.ua/oauth/authorize/?client_id=123&response_type=code&state=x93ld3v&scope=read+write+v2&redirect_uri=http://myadomain.com/auth/connect` (Note: this will be a get call, you must redirect to this url )

where you parameters are:

```
{
"client_id": 123,
"response_type": code,
"state": x93ld3v,
"scope": "read write v2",
"redirect_uri': "http://myadomain.com/auth/connect"
}
```

You also need to add in a logic in backend server or UI whichever is server in the redirect_uri to handle params posted by `olx` server to make further calls for auth token.

Once the server authenticates, it will redirect to the `redirect_uri` with `code` and `state`. You can match this state with your state to ensure that this is the correct code. `Code` is your authorizer for current session which will be required in next step.

You can then use this code again to make a `POST` call over `olx` api to retrieve auth token ( endpoint: `/api/open/oauth/token`).

```
{
  "grant_type": "authorization_code",
  "client_id": "",
  "client_secret": "",
  "code": "",
  "scope": "v2 read write",
  "redirect_uri": "http://myadomain.com/auth/connect"
}
```

You must receive an access token and a refresh token which you can use as per your needs.

You can refer [olx.ua Auth documentation](https://developer.olx.ua/api/doc#section/Authentication/Grant-type:-authorization_code) for more details.

Comment: authorization_uri, state = olx.create_authorization_url(authorization_base_url)

Answer (score 0):

```
authorization_uri, state = olx.create_authorization_url(authorization_base_url)
```

in authorization_uri, i get string  `https://www.olx.ua/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=12345&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fru%2F&scope=v2+write+read&state=6yDKvzjFfN0uXrGJMUUUgjz3pzNilB`

which I send `response = requests.request("GET", authorization_uri, headers=headers, data=payload)`

How to correctly send a request to get redirect URL with  code